# Java: Thread wont wait

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have been trying to get this thread to wait, but it doesnt wait or throw an exception or do anything... (I created a new Thread to run the thread because otherwise my gui freezes due to calling the wait method on the edt)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Sandbox extends JFrame {

boolean paused = false;
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("running...");
        }
    }
};

private JButton button;
public Sandbox() throws Exception {
    thread.start();
    setSize(300, 150);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    add(button = new JButton("Pause"));
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized(thread) {  
                    try {
                        if(button.getText().equals("Pause")) {
                            thread.wait();
                            button.setText("Resume");

                        } else if(button.getText().equals("Resume")) {
                            thread.notify();
                            button.setText("Pause");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }});
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Sandbox();
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `wait` on `Thread` objects. Use `join` to wait until it completes. `wait/notify` are used to have condition variable behavior.

Comment: I dont think the thread will ever die though... Its in a while loop thats continues indefinitely

Comment: I think you don't understand what `wait` method does. What do you expect to happen when you call `thread.wait()`?

Comment: I expect the thread to stop printing out "running...", and wait until I call notify();

Comment: `wait` can only stop thread which calls this method, not any other. You probably need some thread interruption.

Comment: I have tried using wait inside the class I needed to wait, that does not work either

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing strings you need to use `equals()` and not `==`

```
if(button.getText().equals("Pause")) {
    thread.wait();
    button.setText("Resume");

} else if(button.getText().equals("Resume")) {
    thread.notify();
    button.setText("Pause");
}
```

But using wait and notify will probably not really do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I understand, this was just rough code to get to a problem ive been dealing with for quite some time. Well what else can I use?